# Redirigir error try catch en PHP

Tags: php, pdo, try-catch

Estoy intentando hacer un INSERT en una tabla al campo id_prodf, pero en la tabla tiene la restriccion de que sea UNICO, ya que se trata de una lista de deseos y no puedes agregar un mismo producto como favorito.
El probela es que al momento de hacer el INSERT me da el siguiente error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3' for key 'id_prodf'

Pero se queda ahi, yo quisiera redirigir con de vuelta a listadeseos.php

esta es mi funcion que guarda en la tabla lista_deseos

```
public function guardar_listadeseos($pid,$id_usu) {
        $sql="INSERT INTO lista_deseos (id_prodf, id_usuariof) VALUE (?,?)";
        try{
            $smt=$this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $smt->execute(array( $pid,$id_usu ));
        }catch(Eception $e){
           echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

y este de esta forma es como llamo a la funcion en la pagina producto.php, donde se encuentra el boton de agregar a lista de deseos.

```
$usuario = $_SESSION['USUARIO'];
    $id_usu = $usuario->id_usu;
$obj = new Productos();

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $pid = $_GET['id'];
        $obj->guardar_listadeseos($pid,$id_usu);
        if($obj === true ){
            echo "<script>location.href='listadeseos.php'</script>";
        }else{
            echo "<script>location.href='listadeseos.php?error'</script>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<script>location.href='listadeseos.php'</script>";
    }
```

Ya intenté colocar un header("location:listadeseos.php") en el catch
intente con el die(); y con un script window.location, pero ninguno funcionó.

Comment: Hay varios errores de lógica. 1º. Si la columna ID de la tabla es autoincremental, ante cada intento de inserción ese valor aumentará, aunque no se inserte. Significa que si haces por ejemplo 500 intentos erróneos (imaginemos un código que se repite en bucle) si el ID actual está en 1000, habrá un salto de 500 y el próximo insert exitoso registrará el ID 1501. No es algo demasiado grave pero se puede evitar si por ejemplo antes de lanzar el INSERT haces una verificación sobre la existencia de ese registro...

Comment: ... 2º No entiendo por qué el último `else` redirige al mismo lugar que el primer `if`.  En la lógica de tu programa, creo yo, no debería ser lo mismo que un registro se inserte y que el GET no traiga el dato adecuado. Esto último, creo, debería más bien tratado como un error del tipo: *no se envió el dato esperado*. Aquí tu lo tratas como si un INSERT hubiese ocurrido. ¿No es esa una lógica contradictoria?

Comment: Lo del ultimo else, es por si entran a ese archivo sin que exista un id desde la URL, pero es cierto, lo tengo que cambiar a POST, y poner el id del producto en un input hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

- Tenés un error tipográfico en `Eception`, debería ser `Exception` (específicamente `\Exception` si es que no lo estás incluyendo).
- El `Try-Catch` que tenés armado hace un `echo` si se produce una excepción. Si no querés mostrar el error, sacá el `echo`.
- Dentro del `try` no devolvés nada, sin embargo estás comparando `if ($obj === true)`. Y en todo caso deberías guardar en $obj (u otra variable) el *resultado* de `guardar_listadeseos()`.

```php
public function guardar_listadeseos($pid, $id_usu)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO lista_deseos (id_prodf, id_usuariof) VALUE (?,?)";

    try {
        $smt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        return $smt->execute(array($pid, $id_usu));
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Dentro del `try` devuelvo el resultado de [execute](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php) ya que retorna un boolean. En el `catch` saqué el `echo` para que no se muestre el error, pero por ahí lo querés devolver y mostrarlo después de redireccionar, no lo se.

```php
$usuario = $_SESSION['USUARIO'];
$id_usu = $usuario->id_usu;
$obj = new Productos();

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $pid = $_GET['id'];
    $resultado = $obj->guardar_listadeseos($pid, $id_usu);

    if ($resultado === true) {
        echo "<script>location.href='listadeseos.php'</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>location.href='listadeseos.php?error'</script>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<script>location.href='listadeseos.php'</script>";
}
```

En vez de comparar directamente `$obj`, guardo lo que devuelve `guardar_listadeseos()` en `$resultado`.

Comment: Es correcto, tenia mal escrito Exception, en otras funciones si lo tenia de forma correcta, eso era todo el problema, muchas gracias!